# Kafka on the server failed the next day。（EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client,）

Tags: java, apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

The Kafka service I deployed on the server passed the test a few days ago and was running normally. Later, no other operations were carried out.

Then the service call failed today. I went online and looked at it. It's normal these days. Just this afternoon, the service hung up. Looking at the log, it seems to say that the Kafka service is restarted automatically, and then conflicts with the ID of zookeeper.

Restart the service. Everything is normal. Google doesn't have a good solution. What's the reason?

The following is the relevant log, please help to see, thank you

```
[2021-11-06 14:43:29,139] WARN Unexpected exception (org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn)
EndOfStreamException: Unable to read additional data from client, it probably closed the socket: address = /159.89.4.236:59168, session = 0x0
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.handleFailedRead(NIOServerCnxn.java:163)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxn.doIO(NIOServerCnxn.java:326)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.NIOServerCnxnFactory$IOWorkRequest.doWork(NIOServerCnxnFactory.java:522)
    at org.apache.zookeeper.server.WorkerService$ScheduledWorkRequest.run(WorkerService.java:154)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

````
[2021-11-06 15:00:18,301] INFO Completed load of Log(dir=/tmp/kafka-logs/__consumer_offsets-46, topicId=dPs0Kq4ERHKDaR440Nt8qA, topic=__consumer_offsets, partition=46, highWatermark=0, lastStableOffset=0, logStartOffset=0, logEndOffset=0) with 1 segments in 20ms (53/53 loaded in /tmp/kafka-logs) (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-11-06 15:00:18,303] INFO Loaded 53 logs in 2350ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-11-06 15:00:18,303] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 300000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-11-06 15:00:18,304] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2021-11-06 15:00:18,838] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=forwarding]: Starting (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,148] INFO Updated connection-accept-rate max connection creation rate to 2147483647 (kafka.network.ConnectionQuotas)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,165] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,237] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Created data-plane acceptor and processors for endpoint : ListenerName(PLAINTEXT) (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,282] INFO [BrokerToControllerChannelManager broker=0 name=alterIsr]: Starting (kafka.server.BrokerToControllerRequestThread)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,400] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-DeleteRecords]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,400] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Fetch]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,400] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-Produce]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,409] INFO [ExpirationReaper-0-ElectLeader]: Starting (kafka.server.DelayedOperationPurgatory$ExpiredOperationReaper)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,451] INFO [LogDirFailureHandler]: Starting (kafka.server.ReplicaManager$LogDirFailureHandler)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,530] INFO Creating /brokers/ids/0 (is it secure? false) (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,566] ERROR Error while creating ephemeral at /brokers/ids/0, node already exists and owner '72057654275276801' does not match current session '72057654275276802' (kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,572] ERROR [KafkaServer id=0] Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException$NodeExistsException: KeeperErrorCode = NodeExists
    at org.apache.zookeeper.KeeperException.create(KeeperException.java:126)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.getAfterNodeExists(KafkaZkClient.scala:1904)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient$CheckedEphemeral.create(KafkaZkClient.scala:1842)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.checkedEphemeralCreate(KafkaZkClient.scala:1809)
    at kafka.zk.KafkaZkClient.registerBroker(KafkaZkClient.scala:96)
    at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:319)
    at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:109)
    at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,596] INFO [KafkaServer id=0] shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2021-11-06 15:00:19,597] INFO [SocketServer listenerType=ZK_BROKER, nodeId=0] Stopping socket server request processors (kafka.network.SocketServer)```
````

Comment: Have you figured out what was the problem? Seeing the same issue in my setup.